# Azure AD B2C Sign ons from America

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure AD B2C instance with only myself on it (testing).

My test account shows login activity from America despite myself being in the UK. The timestamps also don't match known activity.

Does anyone know what causes these? It is extremely unlikely that I have been'hacked' so I think this must be some kind of background Microsoft process but can't find any documentation about it.

Not sure what info is useful to debug so let me know and I can update the question.

Example event in Sign in logs below

Date 9/19/2020, 4:08:44 AM

Request ID 39a44f55-5afc-43c8-92b6-d2e515aa0d00

User (Me)

Application CPIM PowerShell Client

Status Success

IP address 17.57.26.66

Location Atlanta, Georgia, US

Conditional access Not Applied

Comment: Are you using any VPN?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. No, I am using a mobile app on a normal home network and the Microsoft.Client.Identity library.

Comment: If you are still facing the issue please raise a support ticket by following the instruction [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/support-options).

Comment: Unfortunately as this is a personal project I don’t have paid support and the portal directed me here for help.

Comment: I dont think this is related to hacking. If this is a B2C then most probably the above activity might be related to Powershell module (as you can see the above log talks about the application, "CPIM Powershell client" may have ran your custom policies).

Comment: Yeah that is certainly my thought process as well. I tried Googling and checking the documentation and didn’t find anything though. Was kind of hoping for some kind of confirmation from Microsoft as a first glance it just doesn’t look right.

Answer (score 1):

As Dev Mentioned in the comments the activity is related to B2C custom policy user login.
The AAD sign in logs are not meant for B2C. The relevant logs are Audit Logs menu in B2C blade. Those look like AAD logs for the B2C tenant.
Read this article on what we offer for B2C tenants. You can see sign in info about a user into an app using this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-audit-logs?tabs=applications